# servlet extending another servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I was going thorugh a recent code which was written in servlet. The servlet hierarchy is like this, There is a servlet A which is extended by servlet B extended by servlet C,D,E,F.

Now in my web.xml I have 5 urls configured for these servlets all are mapped to servlet A. So my mapping looks like

URL- /downloadservlet - Class - Servlet A
URL- /readcontent - Class servlet A 
URL- /getdetails - Class servlet A ..  etc etc

Now when I wanted to execte the doPost method in servlet D how can I achieve it? because this request can also be served by C or E or F.

The application works correctly but I could not understand how the request is routed to the correct servlet. Any explaination on this is very much appreciated.

Comment: By the URL mapping, the same as every other Servlet. In your example, B,C,D,E and F are unused. Everything is mapped to A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servlet itself has nothing to do with inheritance. It will call exactly the same class as provided in servlet tag of your web.xml file, e.g. if you want to map a class org.company.D to a servlet, you would need to write something like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletd</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.company.D</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

and then map the 'servletd' to a URL that it should listen on:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletd</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/some-path</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```